# Having trouble with loop in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement

I am trying to get my code to loop back to the beginning of the program after the user completes one of the options.  I cannot seem to figure out how to get it to work properly.  Here is my code so far

```
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int num1;
        int num2;
        int num3;

        boolean opt1Done = false;
        System.out.println("Select your next step");
        System.out.println("1: Enter three numbers between 1 and 100.");
        System.out.println("2: Order your number in ascending order");
        System.out.println("3: Determine if the three inputs form a triangle");
        System.out.println("4: Exit");

        int answer = console.nextInt();
        num1 = console.nextInt();
        num2 = console.nextInt();
        num3 = console.nextInt();

        if (answer == 1) {
            //do whatever for option 1
            System.out.println("Enter a value for num1 between 1 and 100.");
            System.out.println("Enter a value for num2 between 1 and 100.");
            System.out.println("Enter a value for num3 between 1 and 100.");

            opt1Done = true;
      } else if (answer == 2) {
        if (opt1Done) {
                //...... do whatever to order the numbers
            int[] arraynum;
            arraynum = new int[3];

            arraynum[0] = num1;
            arraynum[1] = num2;
            arraynum[2] = num3;

            Arrays.sort(arraynum);

            int i;

            for (i=0; i < arraynum.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("num:" + arraynum[i]);
            }

            } else {
                System.out.println("you must complete Step 1 before Step 2");
            }
      } else if (answer == 3) {
        if (opt1Done) {
                //... do whatever to determine if triangle or not
                if (num1+num2>num3 && num1+num3>num2 && num2+num3>num1)
                {   
                    System.out.print("TRIANGLE");
                }
                else
                {   
                    System.out.print("NO TRIANGLE");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("you must complete Step 1 before Step 3");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I need it so that after the user enters 2 and completes option 2, the program will then go back to the beginning and ask again to choose which option the user wants.  How can I get this to work properly?  Also if anything else is wrong with the code that I do not see please let me know.  Thanks

Comment: Simply put your code in while(true) loop with one break condition in the input.

Comment: The do while loop demonstrated in radically's answer is the best solution. The do while ensures that the code executes AT LEAST once. The while condition at the bottom cause the code to loop. For the while condition, I suggest you use `while(scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase ("y"))`. The allows your user to enter a lower or uppercase y and the loop still works. If you any questions be sure to ask em and tag me when you ask.

Comment: ok so I tried the do while loop and I'm getting an error on the scanner saying scanner cannot be resolved @JohnnyCoder

Comment: @Will Could you do an edit and post the code that where you put in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is put this whole bunch of code in while loop which will always be true  and ask the user input again at end. If user presses 4 which i think is exit just exit the program by using break in your while loop.

Comment: is correct, however it would be cleaner to put this code into a separate method and call that method from within your loop.  Option4 can do a `System.exit`

Comment: Yes @ScaryWombat you are right.. code to get user input should be in separate method. Its just that system.exit scares me from the time it once stopped my web server... :) but yes it will work too..

Answer (score 1):

```
int input;
do {
 //---
 //The rest of your logic
 //---
} while(input != 4);
```

Comment: Best solution and most common sense one.+1.

Comment: I tried this and it did loop the program back to the beginning however the code makes me input the option 4-5 times before actually doing that option and the program won't store the numbers from option one into num1 num2 and num3.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
Boolean p = true;
while(p){
        System.out.println(
            " Select an option:\n" +
            "1: Enter three numbers between 1 and 100.\n" +
            "2: Order your number in ascending order\n"+
            "3: Determine if the three inputs form a triangle\n"+
            "4: Exit\n"
         );
         switch(){
           case 1:
                .
                .
                .
           case 4:
               System.exit();
          }
}
```

Comment: tried this code on the program and when I run it, the program doesn't return anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't return anything"?

Comment: it prints nothing out, no part of the System.out.printlns appear to the user